# How to find cell partitions can be accessed from a partition in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, accessibility, partitioning

I have a cell partition like `A={{1} {2 3 4} {5}}`. I should find all partitions can be accessed from this partition by merging some cells into one cell or splitting a cell into some cells.

For partition A, the results partitions are:

- parttions obtains by merging the cells:
  `{{1 2 3 4}{5}}, {{1 5}{2 3 4}}, {{1} {2 3 4 5}} {{1 2 3 4 5}}`
- parttions obtains by splitting a cell:
  `{{1}{2}{3 4}{5}}, {{1}{3}{2 4}{5}}, {1}{4}{2 3}{5}},{{1}{2 3}{4}{5}}, {{1}{2 4}{3}{5}},{{1}{2}{3 4}{5}}`

I know for finding the accessible partitions by the merge action, I should find all combination k of |A| of cells, where `2<=k<=|A|`.

But, I don't know how to find all partitions can be formed by splitting.

How can I do this?
Thank you

Comment: `A={{1} {2 3 4} {5}}` or `A={[1] [2 3 4] [5]}` which is it ?

Comment: I saw the edit made by @Root125. So wanted to make sure that things where not mixed up.

Comment: @RijulSudhir , Please refer to this url : https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51406137/revisions

Comment: A={{1} {2 3 4} {5}}  is true. I have a cell contains some cells.

Answer (score 0):

```
            function Acc_Parts=Merge_Split(in_part)
            %Returns all partitions can be accessed from the input partition


            si_part=size(in_part,2);              %number of cells in the input partition
            Bell_Number=ceil(sum((1:2*N).^N./cumprod(1:2*N))/exp(1)); %N is the number of elements in in_part partitions 
            Acc_Parts=cell(Bell_Number,1);

            %% merge some cells to form new cell
            %should find any combination k of si_part, where 2<=k<=si_part, and combine the selected cells to form a new cell

            l=1;                                % count the new partitions
            for k=2:si_part                     % choose k cells of si_part cells to merge them into one cell

                V=nchoosek(in_part,k);      %A MATLAB function gives a matrix containing all possible combinations of the elements of input vector taken k at a time
                s_V=nchoosek(si_part,k);    %Number of rows of comb. (Number of the possible combinations)
                celldisp(V)

                for i=1:s_V
                    cp_part=in_part;
                    b1=V{i,1};

                    for h=1:si_part         %delete this cell from cp_part
                        f=0;
                        if(b1==cell2mat(in_part(h)))
                            cp_part(h)=[];
                            f=1;
                            break;
                        else
                        end
                    end

                    for j=2:k
                        b2=V{i,j};
                        si_cpart=size(cp_part,2);
                        for h=1:si_cpart            %delete this cell from cp_part
                            f=0;
                            if(b2==cell2mat(cp_part(h)))
                                cp_part(h)=[];
                                f=1;
                                break;
                            else
                            end
                        end
                        celldisp(cp_part)

                        b1=[b1 b2];         %merge cells
                    end

                    new_coal={b1};

                    if(isempty(cp_part)==0)
                        Acc_Parts{l}=[new_coal,cp_part];
                    else
                        Acc_Parts{l}=[new_coal];
                    end
                    l=l+1;
                end

            end

            %% split a cell to some cells
            for i=1:si_part 
                cp_part=in_part;
                cp_coal=in_part{i};
                si_coal=size(cp_coal,2);    

                if (si_coal>=2)                 %check all cells to find cells with 2 or more elements
                    cp_part(i)=[];

                    parts=partitions(in_part{i});
                    si_parts=size(parts,1);

                    for k=2:si_parts
                        if(isempty(cp_part)==0)
                            Acc_Parts{l}=[parts{k},cp_part];
                        else
                            Acc_Parts{l}=[parts{k}];
                        end
                        l=l+1;
                    end

                else ;
                end
            end

            Acc_Parts(all(cellfun('isempty',Acc_Parts),2),:) = [];

            Acc_Parts
            celldisp(in_part)
            celldisp(Acc_Parts)

            end
```

Comment: I hope it will be helpful. 
You can find the source code for partitions function from this address: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/24185/versions/2/previews/PARTITIONS/partitions.m/index.html?access_key=